# Mock or Stub DateTime in Minitest ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, mocking, minitest

I'm implementing an last_active_at attribute on an User model, which will be updated every time a user visits a page on the website.

When trying to test the setting of this attribute with a mock on the datetime, I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'expect' for DateTime:Class`.

Here is my test in the file chapter_controller_test.rb :

```
test "save user last activity timestamp" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, student_type: User::REMOTE)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  some_date = DateTime.new(2014, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1)
  DateTime.expect(:now, some_date)
  get :index
  assert_equal(some_date, user.last_active_at)
end
```

And the implementation in ApplicationController :

```
before_filter :record_activity

def record_activity
  if current_user && current_user.remote?
    current_user.last_active_at = DateTime.now
    current_user.save
  end
end
```

I'm using minitest 5.1

Answer (score 4):

This is minitest but for rails (your case), from 4.1 onwards you may use `travel_to`

```
travel_to Date.new(1986, 10, 25) do
  Date.current == Date.new(1985, 10, 25) # Marty! You've gotta come back with me!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't use `expect` this way. Try something like this instead:

```
test "save user last activity timestamp" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, student_type: User::REMOTE)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  some_date = DateTime.new(2014, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1)
  DateTime.stub :now, some_date do
    get :index
    assert_equal(some_date, user.last_active_at)
  end
end
```

I can't check that on my own at the moment, but give it a shot!

Good luck!

Comment: For more complex time/date-related tests, the timecop gem is excellent https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

Comment: Aggree! What I tried to show here is a way of stubbing/creating mocks for Minitest in general. Using `DateTime` is just an example of stubbing a method call. For any time-dependant tests `timecop` is a way to go - let's make it clear! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to stub (was more interesting in that case than to mock) by using the gem mocha, and my test now looks like this:

```
test "save user last activity timestamp" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, student_type: User::REMOTE)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  some_date = DateTime.new(2014, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1)
  DateTime.stubs(:now).returns(some_date)
  get :index
  user.reload
  assert_equal(some_date, user.last_active_at)
end
```

Works fine for me.